# How to solve simple pendulum equation and this equation ( $mv' + bv = mg$ )

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, laplace-transform, classical-mechanics

I would like to know the steps to solve the simple pendulum (with small angle so it will be linear) 
and the equation of  free falling mass with air resistance which is ( $mv' + bv = mg$ ). 
I just wanna note that am a beginner in differential equations and wanna ask if there are other methods to solve these 2 equations other than separable and Laplace thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks alot

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici oh sir am very sorry if it looks rude but English isn't my main language so I may say it in a rude form by mistake. sorry again

Comment: Your second equation does not contain air resistance, that would be $mv'+c|v|v=mg$. As it is, it is more some rolling friction equation. You are asking about introductory examples for the more general topic of linear equations with constant coefficients?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici pleased to meet you sir, I am from Egypt

Comment: @LutzLehmann I got this equation by describing a mass  free-falling under gravity but with air resistance under the assumption “the force of air resistance is proportional to the speed of the mass and opposes the direction of motion”  thanks a lot for correcting and my question is how to solve it and the simple pendulum equation using ( Laplace transform)

Comment: Air resistance is quadratic in the velocity. In some fixed time span the displaced volume is proportional to the speed, and the air molecules get "freely bounced away", imparting an impulse change that is also proportional to the speed of the object. Thus the impulse lost in that time segment is quadratic in the speed. In water the displaced volume is just "moved to the side", thus the work done is mostly linear in the speed.